# Using a Loop to make a single dataframe from columns of multiple dataframes

Tags: r, loops

I want to take certain columns from multiple data frames and combine them into one data frame.  I am looking to combine Discrimination Scores from multiple days (each day is its own data frame).  I could have upwards of 30 data frames and manually writing out each line of code is a pain and was looking for something more efficient.

This is what I have been doing:

```
#Day 1
MTDay1 <- data.frame(MTD1$Animal.ID, MTD1$End.Summary...Corrects..1.)
MTDay1$Day <- "Day 1"
colnames(MTDay1) <- c("Subject",
                    "Correct",
                    "Day")

#Day3
MTDay3 <- data.frame(MTD3$Animal.ID, MTD3$End.Summary...Corrects..1.)
MTDay3$Day <- "Day 3"
colnames(MTDay3) <- c("Subject",
                      "Correct",
                      "Day")

#Day4
MTDay4 <- data.frame(MTD4$Animal.ID, MTD4$End.Summary...Corrects..1.)
MTDay4$Day <- "Day 4"
colnames(MTDay4) <- c("Subject",
                      "Correct",
                      "Day")


#Combine Days
MTdf <- rbind(MTDay1,
              MTDay3,
              MTDay4)
```

I want to take the Subject and Percent Correct columns from each day and combine them into a new data frame.  There has to be a more efficient way to do this, perhaps a loop?

Any information would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: *each day is its own data frame*...how are you doing this? Try saving all days in a list for list-wise operations. Please show how `MTD#` objects are created.

Comment: MTD# is just the raw exported data for the task, I read them into the environment with read.csv

Comment: You should be reading them into a list: `MTD_List <- lapply(list.files(...), function(f) read.csv(f))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a named list of dataframes with `eapply` or `mget`. Then use `Map` to iterate elementwise through list's names and dataframe elements. Also, name each column in `data.frame`. Finally, run a `do.call` to rowbind all dataframe elements of new list.

```
# EQUIVALENT CALLS (CHOOSE EITHER)
df_list <- eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(d) d)[c("MTD1", "MTD2", "MTD3", ...)]
df_list <- mget(c("MTD1", "MTD2", "MTD3", ...))

df_process <- function(name, df) {    
     # ASSIGN NAMED COLUMNS IN data.frame CALL
     data.frame(Subject = df$Animal.ID, 
                Correct = df$End.Summary,
                #... other columns ...,
                Day = gsub("MTD", "Day ", name))
}

new_list <- Map(df_process, names(df_list), df_list)

MTdf <- do.call(rbind, new_list)
```

Alternatively, read source files into a named list and use `tryCatch` to output empty dataframes from problem files.

```
df_list <- list(
     PID1 = read.csv(...),
     PID2 = read.csv(...),
     PID3 = read.csv(...)     
)

df_process <- function(name, df) {   
     tryCatch( 
         # ASSIGN NAMED COLUMNS IN data.frame CALL
         data.frame(Subject = df$Animal.ID, 
                    Correct = df$End.Summary.Corrects,
                    Seconds = df$End.Condition,
                    Day = gsub("PID", "Day ", name))
     , error = function(e)
         # RETURN EMPTY DATAFRAME
         data.frame(Subject = NA, 
                    Correct = NA,
                    Seconds = NA,
                    Day = gsub("PID", "Day ", name))
     )
}

new_list <- Map(df_process, names(df_list), df_list)

MTdf <- do.call(rbind, new_list)
```

Comment: When I used mget, I get an "invalid first argument" error. And when I use eapply, I get an "invalid subscript type 'list' error.

Comment: Whoops! I should have used character vectors and not actual dataframe objects. Please try now.

Comment: Woo! Thank you so much for the help!  This saves so much time!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help. But again, if you need to use `mget` or `eapply`, likely there is an opportunity to build your list of objects at the source. See my above comment under your post.

Comment: Parfait, this code has been working wonderfully.  However, I recently switched to a new task, and therefore I have new csv files to read in.  Everything is the same, except "MTD#" is now "PID#".  Unfortunately now, the line `new_list <- Map(df_process, names(df_list), df_list)` gives me the following error " Error in data.frame(Subject = df$Animal.ID, Correct = df$End.Summary...Corrects..1.,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 16, 0, 1"

Any idea why I am getting this error?  The csv files are exactly identical to the "MTD#" files that you originally used to make the code.

Comment: Did you replace all *MTD* with *PID*? `eapply` or `mget` will return nothing since there are no MTD* named objects. Once again, read data files directly into list to avoid relying on environment names.

Comment: I replaced every MTD with PID, throughout my entire script. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/ibT9oij.png) is a screenshot of how I set it up.  I'm not sure why I am getting the error.  The new csv files are 100% identical to the _MTD_ files, the only thing that differs is the name.

Comment: I doubt they are 100% identical (maybe very close). Error raised means a `NULL` is being passed into `data.frame` or a column that does not exist. Since those are very strange names, carefully check them in each csv, particularly the many periods.

Comment: I also add an alternative solution reading csvs into a named list without need of calling `eapply` or `mget`. I even add a `tryCatch` to return empty dfs on error where you can verify *new_list* and see which original dfs (or days) did not behave well. Be very careful with this as code should not stop running but you need to check for reason of empty dfs.